# Shifting an object in an Array list left or right Randomly

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on some practice on an Array problem in Java. I know that when you declare an object, you can put it in an array an move right or left. However, is there anyway that you can move it randomly to left or right?

In this practice, I set the array size to 100. I want to check if the cell is empty. If it is not empty, then the object ( Bear and fish) move left or right (randomly). If it is empty, it do something else.

```
     For example:
    //Create an Array
    //Add objects into array
        Animal[] river = new Animal[100];
        Fish f = new Fish();
        Bear b = new Bear();
        river[0]= f;
        river[1]= b;

            for (int i = 0; i<river.length; i++){
                  if (river[i] != null){
        //not sure how to shift byte right and left 
        }
```

Any ideas? help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't confuse, `ArrayList != Array`

Comment: thank you for your reply. I know that I am working on an Array. I am not sure how to implement the shifting method

Comment: One question, why would you like to do this? What's the purpose?

Comment: @Christian: I'm guessing he's trying to make the bear chase the fish, although in this example his fish will be chasing the bear.

Comment: For random left-right (or any other binary) decision you can use `nextBoolean()` method of `java.util.Random class`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I don't know. This seems a little bit strange to me. Another question, he want's to just move one object at a time? Or all objects in the array? I'm saying this because of his `for-loop`.

Comment: Thanks guys. What i am trying to do is 
I want to move each animals one space, until there are no fish or you have performed 100 cycles. But each time I move a animal, I want to look ahead one space to see what's in that space (cell).

Comment: perhaps this will clear up a bit?

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking in too wide terms. Shifting to the left or right is really just removing it from the current position and adding it to the other.

That brings you to pseudocode like this:

```
if position is occupied
  store animal on position in variable
  empty the position
  put animal from variable in another position
```

whereas the last step depends on your criterium. You could just do `position + 1` or `position - 1`, or you can actually use a random spot using the [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

By "shifting" left and right, it sounds like what you want is to randomly swap an item in the `river` array with the item adjacent to it. As others have mentioned, you can use the [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class to generate random values.

I would generate one of `{-1, 0, 1}`: if the number is `0`, the item doesn't move; if the number is `-1`, swap the current item (`river[i]`) with its left neighbor (`river[i-1]`); if the number is `1`, swap the current item (`river[i]`) with its right neighbor (`river[i+1]`). Be sure to implement a `swap` method, and be careful to not exceed the array's bounds.

---

EDIT:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i=0; i<river.length; i++)
{
    int shift = rnd.nextInt(3) - 1; // -1, 0, or 1

    switch(shift)
    {
        case -1: // swap to the left
            if (i > 0)
                swap(river, i, i-1);
            break;

        case 1: // swap to the right
            if (i < river.length-1)
                swap(river, i, i+1);
            break;

        default:
            // no shift
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. so would you suggest something like this?
for (int i = 0; i < river.length -1;i++){
 river[i] = river[i+1];  
       System.out.println(i);